# Python TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask

How i can fix this problem.it is on script im using or it is on the Python.Im using Debian OS
And trying to install this code
https://github.com/rkubik/paypark

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/var/paypark/paypark/frontend/auth.py", line 14, in auth_login
    if current_user.is_authenticated() or form.validate_on_submit():
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Comment: `current_user.is_authenticated` instead of `current_user.is_authenticate()`, or maybe `form.validate_on_submit` instead of `form.validate_on_submit()` in `form.validate_on_submit`. Probably one of those was turned from a method to a property. Just edit the source file for a quick fix. There is also an [issue](https://github.com/rkubik/paypark/issues/1), but since this repo was created 2 years ago, I doubt it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Artyer. This sort of python issue happens when methods are changed to properties or vice versa, but not all of the calling code has been verified and changed to match. I am guessing that its Flask-Login that has been changed but the author of the code you are using hasn't updated anything for 2 years as pointed out. `current_user.is_authenticate()` is the most likely cause from some digging around but changing both or either will soon see. You may find other instances also.